# Sailsjs grunt .svn error during lifting

Tags: sails.js

I have imported my project in svn when I did a checkout and ran the app I got this error I am using sailsjs-0.10.5. I think it is to do with the grunt I am not able to find any solution it works fine in mac not in linux I set the permissin to 0777 even though it is not working here is the error.

verbose: Grunt :: Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...
verbose: Grunt :: ERROR
verbose: Grunt :: >> TypeError: Property '.svn' of object # is not a function
verbose: Grunt :: Warning: Task "default" not found. 
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **

### error:

Aborted due to warnings.
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > TypeError: Property '.svn' of object # is not a function
> >
> > ### Warning: Task "default" not found.

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error: 
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error: 
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error: 
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/var/hosts/chating_room/.tmp` ?
error: 
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME /var/hosts/chating_room/.tmp

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to Gruntfile.js, find `loadTasks` function, add                     `excludeDirs :  /^\.(git|svn)$/`:

Original:

```
function loadTasks(relPath) {
        return includeAll({
                dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, relPath),
                filter: /(.+)\.js$/
        }) || {};
}
```

After:

```
function loadTasks(relPath) {
        return includeAll({
                dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, relPath),
                filter: /(.+)\.js$/,
                excludeDirs :  /^\.(git|svn)$/
        }) || {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem.

FIXED by

Simply deleting .svn folder from

```html
1) task/.svn,
2) config/.svn &
3) register/.svn
```